Python -- tkinter window label not displaying correctly with "relief" option enabled
I'm trying to put a label (including a few words of text + 1 image) in a window. As a learning process, I also used the "relief" option within the label to put a nice border around the label.
But this "relief" doesn't seem to be working as intended:

If I use RAISED or SUNKEN for the "relief" option, then the window just shows the border, but no label (no text, no image).

If I use GROOVE or RIDGE for the "relief" option, then the label (text + image) both display perfectly.


Quick info about my software versions:
=> OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
=> IDE: PyCharm CE
=> Python version: 3.12.5
=> tkinter Tcl version: 8.6 (from importing tkinter and using: print(tkinter.TclVersion))

The following is my code. There's so little in there.
# ===================================================================
# imports and version checking
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(tkinter.TclVersion)

# create a window
window = Tk()

# prepping image to add to label; just some random picture I had laying around
photo = PhotoImage(file='Avatar - bkgnd.png').subsample(4,4)

# create a label, args: container (which is window in this case), and the text option
label = Label(window,
              text="Hello",
              font=("TkDefaultFont",40,"bold","underline"),
              fg='#00ff00',
              bg='black',
              relief=RAISED,      # This option is causing problems; SUNKEN, RAISED, do not work; GROOVE, RIDGE work.
              bd=10,
              padx=20, pady=20,
              image=photo,
              compound=CENTER)

# add label to window
label.pack()

# display the window
window.mainloop()
# ===================================================================

In my research I came across potential macOS issues with tkinter, including several questions & answers here on Stack Overflow, but found no solutions.
Would you happen to have any suggestions as to how I might be able to fix my problem?
It must be so simple, but I'm just not seeing it, and it's driving me crazy.

Catalina? Thats quite an old version of the OS. I don't have access to that version, but your code works fine on my Mac running Sonoma.

@BryanOakley Yeah it's a bit old... but it's the only computer I have at the moment. I did however find a work-around, and will answer my own question with the work-around that I found that worked for me.

Thanks to @cratermoon on Discord, who helped me find a work-around that worked. The work-around is to put a frame around the label.
Sounded convoluted to me initially, but it wasn't difficult to implement, even for me as a beginner in various respects. Basically it's like:
window wrapping around frame -> frame wrapping around label
So in my case, I successfully implemented it as follows:
# ===================================================================
# create a window
window = Tk()

# prepping image to add to label; just some random picture I had laying around
photo = PhotoImage(file='Avatar - bkgnd.png').subsample(4,4)

# CROSS-PLATFORM COMPATIBILITY:
# -----------------------------
#  tcl for macOS Catalina is faulty -- relief doesn't work in label; must do "relief"
#  in frame. So like: window wrapping around frame, frame wrapping around label.
#  ("tkmacosx" is good for buttons only; it has no Label.)
frame = Frame(window, relief=SUNKEN, bd=10)   # Doing "relief" and "bd" options in frame,
frame.pack()                                  #  instead of in label.

# Create label. However, the "master" argument becomes "frame", as we're
#  wrapping the frame around the label.
label = Label(frame,
              text="Hello",
              font=("TkDefaultFont",40,"bold","underline"),
              fg='#00ff00',
              bg='black',
              #relief=SUNKEN,   # Doing "relief" option in frame instead of here in label
              #bd=10,           # Doing "bd" option in frame instead of here in label
              padx=20, pady=20,
              image=photo,
              compound=CENTER)

label.pack()    # Packing label into frame

# display the window
window.mainloop()
# ===================================================================

